# Why am I getting a SecurityException on asp.net mvc when trying to bind to a collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.

It works fine on my machine, but I'm getting this error on the server.

Here is the Stack Trace:

> [SecurityException: Request failed.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor,
>   Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis,
>   Boolean fillCache) +98
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[]
>   args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +1136
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +111
>   System.SecurityUtils.SecureCreateInstance(Type
>   type, Object[] args, Boolean
>   allowNonPublic) +93
>   System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.CreateInstance(Type
>   objectType, Type callingType) +92
>   System.ComponentModel.ReflectedTypeData.GetConverter(Object
>   instance) +346
>   System.ComponentModel.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
>   +63    System.ComponentModel.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
>   +97    System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type
>   type) +23
>   System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.get_IsComplexType()
>   +13    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext) +357
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor
>   propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder
>   propertyBinder) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor
>   propertyDescriptor) +367
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext) +94
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext, Object model) +55
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext) +1228
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext) +385
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor
>   parameterDescriptor) +303
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor) +105
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +329    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +115    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +94
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5()
>   +37    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +55    System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d()
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action
>   f) +7
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action) +23
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8841105    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +184

Here is the method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(Pessoa model, Movimentacao[] movimentacoes, FormCollection form){...}
```

Here is the data that I'm posting to the server:

> IdPessoa=63&input-tab=7&Nome=Andrea+S.+Gomes&CPF=&Identidade=&DataNascimento=&Sexo=f&EstadoCivil.IdEstadoCivil=2&Profissao.IdProfissao=-1&ProfissaoDescricao=&DataConversao=&BatismoData=&BatismoIgreja=&BatismoPastor=&Endereco=&Complemento=&Estado.IdEstado=1&Cidade.IdCidade=1&Bairro.IdBairro=7&CEP=&Referencia=&Telefone1=&Telefone2=&Email=&Messenger=&Twitter=&PessoaVinculo.IdPessoaVinculo=2&Congregacao.IdCongregacao=6&Ativo=true&Ativo=false&Discipulador.IdPessoa-input=&Discipulador.IdPessoa=&UltimaVisita=&Conectado=false&PequenoGrupo.IdPequenoGrupo=-1&Observacao=&Competencia3=false&Competencia1=false&Competencia2=false&movimentacoes%5B0%5D.IdMovimentacao=0&movimentacoes%5B0%5D.Data=&movimentacoes%5B0%5D.MovimentacaoTipo.IdMovimentacaoTipo=-1&submitButton=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not work because on the server you are trying to run this site the security level could be set to low which would restrict reflection code to run. Such things might happen on shared hosts.

Comment: @Vinicius, me? I think you should check this with your hosting provider. Does he support MVC? Can he change the trust level?